# How to create a function interface that computes its output from a vec input using a thread

Tags: rust

I want a worker to process a Vec<&str> from within a function that takes that vector as a parameter.

The worker lives and dies in that function through a `join()`.

However, I cannot just use it from within the thread, first intuitively because it does not seem safe to have the variable be usable from multiple threads, and second because the compiler does not like its lifetime:

> `list` has an anonymous lifetime `'_` but it needs to satisfy a `'static` lifetime requirement

*[Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c93c8f05c6e8d692e427d46fc11bdbe0)*

I do not want it to have a static lifetime, since that would propagate lifetime management complexity to the consumer of the function. Intuitively, it should be feasible, since my intent is for the worker to end before the function returns.

**Approach 1**: Using a local variable with a cloned version of the vector is not sufficient, for reasons that are not perfectly clear to me. I believe that `&str` does not get deeply cloned when the vector does.

The idea, though, is what I want my computer to do: I do want it to have a completely separate copy in RAM moved into the thread, starting with the same string bytes, and decorrelated lifetimes.

**Approach 2**: The same is true when using message passing ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5476dc3092616b95971ef0570a6c4c75)).

**Approach 3**: Boxes, Arc, etc won’t help us here. At least, that maps to my intuition, since I assume the lifetime issue relates to something somewhere in the data structure remaining linked to the parameter.

**Approach 4**: Forcing a deeper clone does not work on `&str` ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=38aec70edd39e17afe1af8215b3554c7)), but it works on `String` ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3690cfd0eaac4b969a7e3c295e5ad83f)).

However, the worker uses library functions that take `&Vec<&str>`, and deref coercion does not work for iterators ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=14b56d876067de2a84a4b3ac0ad8da41)).

> value of type `Vec<&str>` cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=String>`

Is there an approach that works better than those outlined?

The last approach I can think of is to do an unsafe memory copy of the strings, but I wonder whether it might be a little bit outrageous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's missing from approach 4 is the conversion from `Vec<String>` to `Vec<&str>` within your worker.

This can be achieved with a function like this:

```
fn slice_as_ref(s: &[String]) -> Vec<&str> {
    s.iter().map(|s| s.as_str()).collect()
}
```

See it in action here: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3f1f58df851e82e41e527a0b2c26efeb).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn’t realize that the conversion could be done inside the thread but not outside.

Answer (score 0):

You can use crossbeam's [scoped threads](https://docs.rs/crossbeam/latest/crossbeam/fn.scope.html). [This API is also going to be part of the standard library](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/3151).

```rust
fn worker(list: &Vec<&str>) {
    crossbeam::scope(|s| {
        s.spawn(|_| println!("list: {:?}", list));
    })
    .unwrap();
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fa04b10b291488a4edcdc838e57378dc).

(Though note that it is more idiomatic to take `&[&str]` than `&Vec<&str>`).